# Retrieve sharepoint List in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, combobox, sharepoint-2010

I would like retrieve the title of sharepoint List in JS.

My function JS :

```
function retrieveAllListsAllFields() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        ctx.load(web, "Title");

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
        var listTitle = web.get_title() + " Documents";
    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
```

I retrieve the list but i would like use this list in another function for get the documents list of my library in a combo box :

```
function initComboBox(fileslistBox, fileslistBoxDest, selectLibraryFileFieldResult, entityComboBox, yearComboBox, typeComboBox, library, entityValue, currentSiteUrl) {
    function retrieveAllListsAllFields() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        ctx.load(web, "Title");

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
            var listTitle = web.get_title() + " Documents";
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );

    var listBox;
    var i = 0;
    var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
    var entityComboBoxArray = new Array();
    var yearComboBoxArray = new Array();
    var typeComboBoxArray = new Array();

    addItemToArray(entityComboBoxArray, "", "", i);
    addItemToArray(yearComboBoxArray, "", "", i);
    addItemToArray(typeComboBoxArray, "", "", i);

    //init all combox 
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        webURL: currentSiteUrl,
        async: true,
        listName: listTitle,        
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Entity' /><FieldRef Name='Year_Document' /><FieldRef Name='Library' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Library' /><Value Type='Choice'>" + library + " </Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                i++;
                //Add value to combox Array
                alert(listTitle);
                var tmpEntity = $(this).attr("ows_Entity");
                if (tmpEntity != null)
                    addItemToArray(entityComboBoxArray, $(this).attr("ows_Entity"), (tmpEntity).split("#")[1], i);

                var tmpYear = $(this).attr("ows_Year_Document");
                if (tmpYear != null)
                    addItemToArray(yearComboBoxArray, tmpYear, tmpYear, i);

                var tmpType = $(this).attr("ows_File_x0020_Type");
                if (tmpType != null)
                    addItemToArray(typeComboBoxArray, tmpType, tmpType, i);

                //if option already in Result Select, we move it to the destination RadListBox
                if (isOptionContainInSelect(selectLibraryFileFieldResult, $(this).attr("ows_Title")) == true)
                    listBox = fileslistBoxDest;
                else listBox = fileslistBox;
                addNewFilesItem($(this).attr("ows_ID"), $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef"), $(this).attr("ows_Title"), $(this).attr("ows_Entity"), $(this).attr("ows_Year_Document"), $(this).attr("ows_File_x0020_Type"), listBox);
            });


            //Add sorted array value to combobox 
            addArrayItemsToComboBox(entityComboBoxArray.sort(), entityComboBox);
            addArrayItemsToComboBox(yearComboBoxArray.sort(), yearComboBox);
            addArrayItemsToComboBox(typeComboBoxArray.sort(), typeComboBox);
            selectValueForComboBox(entityComboBox, entityValue);
            filterList(fileslistBox, entityComboBox, yearComboBox, typeComboBox);
        }
    }); 
    }
}
```

But i can't retrieve the documents in the library.
The documents don't load in my combo box.

It's not possible of use this "listName: listTitle" ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeQueryAsync` has two parameters: the callback function to run when the query is successful, and the callback function to run if the query runs into any errors.

Any code that depends on the query running successfully should be placed *inside* the success callback function (the first parameter of `executeQueryAsync`).

```
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, 
    function(){
        var listTitle = web.get_title() + " Documents";

        var listBox;
        var i = 0;
        var reggie // ...
        // rest of your code goes here...

    }),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
```